# Can Adobe Premiere CS5.5 or CS6 do clip spanning with a Canon XA10 camera?

Tags: adobe-premiere

I have Adobe Production Premium CS5 and I cannot import natively into premiere clips that are longer than 12 minutes, I have to take the .MTS files into premiere and edit that way. The problem is that when the 2, 3 or 4 .MTS files are back to back, there is a small sound and video glitch where the files join. This is a problem when I am conducting an interview and they are in mid sentence when glitch occurs. In Finalcut Pro X, I can do clip spanning and take a 45 minute clip as 1 piece without dealing with 4 separate .MTS files and there is no glitch when the clips would join together. However, I want to work with Premiere for their Encore and After Effects integration. I tried taking the imported Finalcut Pro X clip into Premiere as 1 solid clip, but Premiere became VERY slow when I did that, so that is not an option.

My question is, does anyone know if Adobe Premiere CS5.5 or CS6 allow me to import Canon XA10 files as a native, single piece of footage without having to reconstruct the .MTS files and avoid the glitches that come with it? I want to upgrade to the new CS6 Suite, but without this feature, it would be pointless.

Comment: According to our [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), this question is off-topic.

Comment: It is off topic but surprisingly, better questions have been closed quicker.